# Connecting 3g dongle requires it to be replugged

Tags: raspbian, networking, usb

I am using a 3g dongle and usb_modeswith. It works fine if I plug the device after the Raspbian Os has booted up. The thing is, it does not connect (wvdial doesnt detect modem) , if the modem is already connected to the pi, and I reboot (or power on the device after shutdown -P -h).

What do I do to make the usb mode switch everytime it detects my device connected. I am making a project that does not have a screen, so it is essential that The Pi connects without replugging and/or extra input.

Right now I have to do the following to connect to the internet(using the dongle)

1. wait for the pi to boot
2. Plug in the modem(replug if already plugged in)
3. run usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf
4. run wvdial

Why do I have to do the following ? Isnt there any way to reduce these steps ?

Comment: Think of a crontab entry to keep checking for the presence of the USB and run the usb_modeswitch... Possible?

Comment: does it make any difference if you plug the 3g dongle into a mains powered hub connected to the Pi?

Comment: I am using the B+, do I need to connect to a powered hub ?

Comment: @Kangkan , could you please give more info on it?

Comment: My modem shows the following id when I connect 12d1:1446 , could you tell me how to check for that and then connect ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my RasPi B+ (with the exact same settings that works fine with a RasPi B). But I'm not using wvdial because the dongle has HiLink.

The USB-switch doesn't seem to work properly with the B+ somehow.

$lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID **12d1:1f01** Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
(should be **12d1:14db** Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.)

Updated to the latest USB-modeswitch (2.2.1, release dated from 2015-01-15) but that didn't solve my problem.

Tested to manually change the ID with:
$sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x1f01 -V 0x12d1 -P 0x14db -M       "55534243123456780000000000000a11062000000000000100000000000000"

And that actually worked.

Then I just made a little shell script to make the dongle work when booting.

$sudo nano /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/modeswitch

And changed the owner to root, the script to be executable by User, Group and World.

$sudo chown root:root /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/modeswitch

$sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/modeswitch

$sudo chmod 755 /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/modeswitch

Then reboot and the dongle works again.